# Lightning + Salesforce DX

Tags: lightning

Is it possible to create a ***lightning component*** from **sfdx** command?

Comment: I've downvoted this question because it shows no effort to research your question prior to asking it. I'd expect this would be something easy to find in official documentation (as Pranay Jaiswal's answer illustrates).

Comment: I've downvoted this question because it shows no effort to research your question prior to asking it.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can,with the following commands.

```
sfdx force:lightning:app:create -n mylightningapp
sfdx force:lightning:component:create -n mylightningcomp
```

More info : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_develop_create_lightning.htm